# Require Webpack bundle -- returns empty object?

Tags: webpack, commonjs

Update -- related: [How to prepend `module.exports =` to webpack bundle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38290718/export-a-webpack-bundle-prepend-module-exports-avoid-empty-object-in-node)

---

I have webpack compile a simple `module.exports = "asdfasdf"` to `foo.js`

In a node `server.js` I have `var foo = require("./foo.js")`

When I `console.log(foo)` I get an empty object `{}`

What am I doing wrong??

My webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./test.js",
    output: {
        filename: "./foo.js"
    },
    target: "node",
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: "babel?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015"
            }
        ]
    },
    devtool: "#source-map"
};
```

Comment: Could you post the contents of the compiled `foo.js`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you are missing the `libraryTarget`-setting. Adding `libraryTarget: "commonjs2"` to the config should fix the issue. [See the webpack-docs about it](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibrarytarget).

Answer (score 9):

In my case I have same problem when using **babel-loader** with Babel 6.
Even when I set

```
"libraryTarget": "commonjs2"
```

I have results:

```
const foo = require('some-module');
console.log(foo) // is {}

const bar = require('some-module').default;
console.log(bar) // is default export of 'some-module'
```

If you want:

```
const foo = require('some-module');
console.log(foo) // is default export of 'some-module'
```

You can use:
[**babel-plugin-add-module-exports**](https://github.com/59naga/babel-plugin-add-module-exports)

**UPDATE:**

The authors of webpack do not recommend using the **babel-plugin** for this.

Webpack 3 has option [**output.libraryExport**](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-libraryexport) (*it is don`t have detailed docs now*)

I tried like this

```
output.libraryExport: 'default'
```

and it resovled the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem since for jest I need @babel plugins. I wrote the whole project with babel-6. Now I tried it again with the suggestion of @mbraint. And it worked! So for webpack output property you need something like below:

```js
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '<output-file-name>.js',
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
        libraryExport: 'default',
        library: '<ProjectName>'
    },
```

Use the naming cases as I show. Happy coding ✌