# Export a webpack bundle / prepend module.exports? Avoid empty object in node?

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to require my bundle.js into my Node server, but apparently the webpack bundle is missing a `module.exports =` before all of the bundle code at the top.

I can manually put `module.exports =` into this bundle, but there has to a programmatic way to specify the bundle should be exportable

Comment: Have you already solved it? did librarytarget work for you? for me it didn't

Comment: @user1269009 yes libraryTarget `umd` lets webpack know to prepend `module.exports = `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried adding

```
libraryTarget: 'umd'
```

to the webpack config.
Have a look at [this](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/#object).