# Require webpack bundle returns empty object

Tags: typescript, webpack

Adding libraryTarget as suggested here: [Require Webpack bundle -- returns empty object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38289019/require-webpack-bundle-returns-empty-object) doesn't help.

webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    target: "node",
    entry: './src/Api.ts',
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js']
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.min.js',
        libraryExport: "umd"  // tried several here
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Api.ts:

```
export class Api {
    test(){

    }
}
```

Then in another project I have (expressjs):

```
const mymodule = require('full_path/dist/bundle.min.js');
console.log(mymodule) # always empty object
```

I was expecting to be able to do `mymodule.test()`

Comment: I'm  not familiar with using umd modules but I think you need to use export default if you're not going to name the export.

Comment: @MichaelKnight `export default class Api {` still empty object

Comment: Then do you have to use require(....).default as well? And do you have to use umd and the require statement? Otherwise you can use es modules which allow tree shaking and I'm familiar with the syntax. Sorry I couldn't be of more use.

Comment: @MichaelKnight I don't see how I can import it in express without require(). webpack builds a file that starts with `!function(e){` which to me looks like it's meant to be run in a browser. Instead, I need to import it in express with require..

Comment: @MichaelKnight solved, it, removed .js from require and added         libraryTarget: "commonjs2"