# Module import return empty object

Tags: typescript, npm, webpack

I try to create npm module using Webpack and TypeScript. After build my package and try to import it, i've an empty object, and not my default exported function.

You can see my configuration :

Webpack.js :

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

const config = {
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts(x)?$/,
        use: ['awesome-typescript-loader'],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              importLoaders: 1
            }
          },
          'postcss-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js']
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*"]
}
```

My module is build, but default import return an empty object. I've try with example function :

```
const test = () => console.log('test');

export default test;
```

`import test from 'my-module-name'; test() // test is not a function`

Anyone have already create npm module using webpack and typescript ?

Thank you community !

Answer (score 3):

Based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38289019/require-webpack-bundle-returns-empty-object), you have to add `libraryTarget: "commonjs2"` to your webpack configuration.

Here's the example:

```js
module.exports = {
    ...
    output: {
        path     : path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename : '[name].js',
        libraryTarget : 'commonjs2' // Add this line
    },
    ...
}
```

I have implemented this solution before and it also works on `TypeScript + Webpack` with similar problem.

Comment: I don't know why this answer has no upvotes. Thanks (this is the only clear answer in all of the web)

Comment: Thanks for the upvotes, folks! Now I can comment :)